# Selecting a single column from all rows for chart range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I want to specify a certain column from all rows (omitting the first few) to be the range for my chart. Currently I input this to specify the range: `L6:L` (note: this automatically changes to `L6:L20` once I click "Update" in the chart data, 20 is the number of rows I have). However, as time goes on, I will be adding rows above row 6 with new data. That is to say, all the current rows will be shifted down by one and there will be new data in row 6. So now the chart should automatically update with the new data point (i.e. the range should be `L6:L21`). However, this doesn't happen because the range automatically changes to `L7:L21`. I've tried using `L$6:L` (and even `L$6:$L`) to specify the range but the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be avoided by including a header row (5th in your case) in the range of the chart. Then the new data points added at the beginning of the data series will be inserted between 5th and 6th row, so the reference L5:L20 will become L5:L21, etc.